# Firebase - How to save data from Facebook Login to Database

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im new to Firebase database

In my app, i've already have the login to facebook with firebase. I save this information like this

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            String name = user.getDisplayName();
            String email = user.getEmail();
            Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
            String uid = user.getUid();
            nameTextView.setText(name);
            emailTextView.setText(email);
            uidTextView.setText(uid);

            try {
                URL img_value = null;
                img_value = new URL(photoUrl+"");
                String cadena  = img_value+"";

                //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(cadena).into(perfil);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
} else {
            goLoginScreen();
        }
```

I can show my information, like Full name, profile pic, etc; but now I want to save in the Firebase database like this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "uid1": {
      "name": "peter parker",

    }
    "uid2": {
      "name": "barry allen",

      }
    "uid3": {
      "name": "bruce banner",

      }    
  }
}
```

As uid1, uid2 ...  the `uid =user.getUid();` I think this would be the key. 
I know I can generate a key for each one with push, but I believe I can put the uid as the key. In the app we will implement a basic chat too.

I've search and tried to code, but I don't get what i need:

```
String value = nameTextView.getText().toString();
    DatabaseReference mRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mUser = mRoot.child("users");

    DatabaseReference  mUid = mUser.child("uid1");
    DatabaseReference  mName = mUid.child("name");

    mName.setValue(value);
```

I'd like to save automatically the names after someone register in the app. Because I will later add a list of Events per user as list of interest(what event he liked to save). 
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code...which would perfectly work for you...

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("users").child("uid1").child("name").setValue(your_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an authentication dart file: auth.dart
  import this packages:
         1)import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
         2)import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
         3)import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';

paste this code:

```
class AuthService {
    static final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    static final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
    final db = Firestore.instance;
    final FacebookLogin facebookLogIn = FacebookLogin();
    final String email;
    final String username;
    AuthService({ this.email, this.username});
    Future<void> signUpWithFacebook() async{
    try {
        var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
        var result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
        if(result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
          final AuthCredential credential = 
      FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
            accessToken: result.accessToken.token,
            );
      final FirebaseUser user = (await 
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
          await 
      db.collection('user').document(user.displayName).setData({'name': 
      user.displayName, 'email': user.email});
          print('signed in ' + user.displayName);
          return user;
        }
      }catch (e) {
        print(e.message);
      }}}
```

On LoginPage
add `final AuthService facebookLogIn = AuthService();` inside the class

and on Button widget put onPressed

```
onPressed: (){facebookLogIn.signUpWithFacebook().whenComplete(() {Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {return MainPage();},),);});},
```